# My Relay suddenly turns on and off, and this happens in a second

Tags: pi-3, python-3, dht22

Well, I had written a code for Automatic Cooling with DHT 11, but I did not get any successful result in it, I want the Relay turn on when the humidity rises up, and I did not have any errors in my code, Please find me a solution!!

This is my code -

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import lcddriver
import time

#Light = 26
Fan = 26

display = lcddriver.lcd()
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

#GPIO.setup(Light, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Fan, GPIO.OUT)

instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=17)

GPIO.output(Fan, False)

def fan_on():
    GPIO.output(Fan, True)
def fan_off():
    GPIO.output(Fan, False)

try:
    while True:
        result = instance.read()


#        if result.is_valid():
#       display.lcd_display_string("Temp : "+str(result.temperature)+" C",1)
#       display.lcd_display_string("Humid : "+str(result.humidity)+"%",2)
#           time.sleep(2)

    if (str(result.humidity)) >= 65:
            fan_on()
            #time.sleep(1)

        elif (str(result.humidity)) < 65:
            fan_off()
            #time.sleep(3)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Cleaning up!")
    display.lcd_clear()
    GPIO.output(Fan, False)
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: i see improperly indented code

Comment: This is a how do I write Python question.  Not specific to the Pi.  How can you get past the while true loop?

Comment: one thing you may want to research is *hysteresis*

Comment: `I did not have any errors in my code` - if that were so, your code would do what you expect

Comment: @joan - to be fair, I think there's just one line (the `if` statement) poorly indented in the question - if the code were exactly as in the question, the relay would never turn on/off "suddenly" (as per question title) or at all

Comment: @JaromandaX Possibly, although I suspect the while loop scope is actually wrong, not a typo.  Setting the GPIO to an output can make the relay change state.

Comment: jsotola, Jaromanda X - all the intendentions are correct and as I told you there were no errors, the inproper intendention is caused when I pasted my code in this forum, well the things are not working as I expected. HOW MY THING SHOULD WORK - When the humidity is greater than or equal to 65, then My ceiling Fan must turn on and when the humidity is less than 65 the my ceiling fan must turned off!!, This is what I wanted, as you can see there is no errors at all and my code looks meaningful as what I have explained here, But what is going wrong, Please help me with it.

Comment: "there is no errors at all"... what do you expect to be the result of comparing a string and a number (`str(result.humidity)>=65`). What do you mean with "error"? Python inherently does not always raise an "error" when the programmer makes a **mistake**...